# DigitalOcean LoadBalancer Kubernetes Traffic Status 0/1. The config dont work with two deployments at the same time

Tags: kubernetes

Good day.

I'm trying deploy some microservice using Java and Spring Boot in DigitalOceand Kubernetes cluster. The first microservice is an Eureka Server library, and I am trying test the environment with a Google app before to continue deploying the other microservices.

I have the next problem implementing two Pods and one LoadBalancer Service in DigitalOcean Kubernetes.

My config is:
The first Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-deployment-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-deployment-1
      role: metrol-network-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-deployment-1
        role: metrol-network-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "400Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
          limits:
            memory: "500Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 10
```

The second Deployment is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: metrol-eureka-server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: metrol-eureka-server
      role: metrol-network-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: metrol-eureka-server
        role: metrol-network-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: 'metrol-eureka-server'
        image: crivera3/metrol-eureka-server:0.0.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8761
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1000Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
          limits:
            memory: "1100Mi"
            cpu: "600m"
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 8761
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8761
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 10
```

The LoadBalancer Service is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: metrol-network-service
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-healthcheck-protocol: "http"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-healthcheck-path: "/actuator/health"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-healthcheck-port: "8761"
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8761
    targetPort: 8761
    name: metrol-eureka
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    name: hello-deployment-1
  selector:
    role: metrol-network-service
```

The outcome of the LoadBalancer Service:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtl24.png)

When I apply this config on Digital Ocean, the LoadBalancer and Droplet don't establish traffic
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4DqV.png)

But, If I delete this apply and delete one of the them, and execute the config again, the LoadBalancer work correctly.

Evidencia #1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCo4h.png)

Evidencia #2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIR44.png)

Evidencia #3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsuCT.png)

Evidencia #4
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjV4A.png)

In other words, both deployments cannot live together, but when I deploy anyone and just one deployment works very well.

PD:

- Node information when I deploy both deployments:
  Allocated resources:
  | Resources | Request |  Limits |
  | -------- | -------- | -------- |
  | CPU   | 1502m (79%)   | 850m (44%)   |
  | Memory| 2526180480(77%)   | 2442294400(74%)   |

---

- Node information when I deploy just one deployment:
  Allocated resources:
  | Resources | Request |  Limits |
  | -------- | -------- | -------- |
  | CPU   | 1302m (68%)   | 600m (31%)   |
  | Memory| 2106750080(64%)   | 1918006400 (58%)   |

```
I have looked information about this but I found did not fix this issue
```

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been running this configuration in other provider's cloud, like for example: Vultr or Linode(Akamai) and this configuration works much more stable. I believe the main reason for this issue is the health check config. e.g:

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 
metadata:   
  name: metrol-network-service  
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/[provider cloud - linode]-loadbalancer-check-timeout: "10"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/[provider cloud - linode]-loadbalancer-check-interval: "15"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/[provider cloud - linode]-loadbalancer-check-attempts: "5"**
```

Another characteristic in my case is: that I implemented a Spring Cloud Netflix environment, and under this strategy, it is normal that every microservice does an HTTP request to register in the Eureka Server, therefore, the health check is involved much more.